# Wait for socket connection to establish (when changing page path), till sending router data to the user

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, socket.io

I need the socket connection to establish before I can send data from the route to the user (otherwise it is not possible).

In **app.js** file I have socket connection logic:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next)
{
    req.sio = sio;
    next();
});

sio.on('connection',
    function(soc)
    {
        console.log('socket connected');
        soc.on('disconnect', function(reason)
        {
            console.log('socket disconnected');
        });
        // and more about socket connection here...
    });
```

In **index.js** file I have route.post logic:

```
router.post('/route1', function(req, res, next) // user is moved from index.js to route1.js if he fills the form
{
    var fromInput = req.body.form_name;
    console.log('DATA passed from INDEX.JS: ' + formInput);

    if ((formInput !== '') && (formInput !== null) && (formInput !== undefined))
    {
        function render()
        {
            //// first we render the page, so the javascript (with socket.io notes) can be read it and then the browser know that socket connection should be established
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject)
            {
                resolve(res.render('route1'));
            });
        }

        // I need to pass some data AFTER the socked connection is established - cause I move to a different page path - using a **router.post** and cause of that socket connection is disconnected - so I need to wait till its usable again. For simplicity let suppose socket connection is established after 2 seconds (it is a simple check for req.soc.connected):

        var soc = false;

        setTimeout(function()
        {
            soc = true; // after 2 sec soc is true (connection is established)
        }, 2000);

        // Now I want to create an interval that will monitor IF socket connection is established every 100ms (so checking won't happen to often - it is not "resource hungry"). If socket connection is not ready the function should call it self (recursion) if the socket connection is established it (function) should fire a promise.

    var arr = [];
    arr.push(exe(100, data));

    function exe(delay, d)
    {
        d = data;
        return new Promise(function(resolve)
        {
            if (d === false)
            {
                setTimeout(function()
                {
                    console.log('wait another ' + delay + ' [ms] - ' + d);
                    return resolve(exe(delay, d));
                }, delay);
            }
            else
            {
                console.log('socket connected!');
                return resolve(d);
            }
        });
    }
    render().then(function()
    {
        return Promise.all(arr).then(function(arr)
        {
            console.log(arr);
        });
    }).then(function()
    {
        console.log('ALL DONE!');
    });
    }
});
```

Comment are in code. If something isn't clear let me know.

@jfriend00
1 - true,
2 - true,
3 - I call **render()** immediately - *so page is loaded and client make a socket connection, then the rest of the code should execute and send the data.*

---

1. yes I did use POST with a form. There could be socket connection between the server and index page - not a problem I can create one, but I dunno what for.
   "or there could be a socket.io connection created in the response to the POST when the browser renders and processes that." I'm trying that one :) I have data in this router.post I want to sent with help of sockets - but first I need to make a connection.
2. as I understand it... user did use form, so path is changed (socket connection is broken), then I'm in router.post I render the page FIRST - so the browser can read it's JS and make a socket connection, BUT you want to say that my response is not finished? So the browser say - ok you want me to render a page, but what now - cause we are NOT finish yet?!

So I will never establish a socket connection, cause I did not properly response? And cause of this **I will not be able to send the data (later code in router.post) cause socket connection is never established cause I did not response properly?** Cause my tests show me otherwise - it is working just fine.

3. you are right - code should works now.
4. till socket connection is established.
5. yea, good catch. I will make some kind of database - redis with express session I guess.

---

So again step by step.
User did fill the form so he is redirect from index.js to route1.js (so it does not make a difference if there is a socket connection BEFORE filling the form or not cause the connection is lost). We are in process of redirecting him (router.post) so I thought I will render the route1 page immediately, so the JS from it can be read by browser, and socket connection can be established (which take time - and IF its possible). So I wait with the data I want to sent to the user (in router.post for example... the form input or whatever) TILL the connection is established, and the send it to the user, with help of socket.io.

The thing is that socket io connection is lost when you change page (path). So I thought (and it could be wrong cause I'm newb) then I wait till it is established, and then send the data. I hope it does make sense.

Answer (score 0):

This structure can never work.  Here's what it looks like you're trying to do:

1. Express server receives a POST request.
2. Then, you try to wait for a socket.io connection to appear before you process the POST and send a response.
3. Finally, when you think you've found a socket.io connection, you then call your `render()` function to "presumably" send a response.

Without really understanding what you're' trying to accompilsh, there are a number of things wrong with the current code:

1. A POST request comes from either an Ajax call or a form POST.  There is no socket.io connection associated directly with either one of those.  There could have been a socket.io connection when the page loaded BEFORE the POST request was sent or there could be a socket.io connection created in the response to the POST when the browser renders and processes that.
2. Even if there was a socket.io connection created when the browser processes the POST response, you're trying to wait for the socket.io connection BEFORE you send the response so you're waiting for something that won't happen until you're done waiting (essentially a deadlock - A won't finish until B finishes, but B can't start until A finishes).
3. This structure `render().then(waitUntil(100, d))` isn't correct.  You MUST pass `.then()` a function reference.  You are passing it a promise (the return value form calling `waitUntil(...)`).  This is the least of your problems though because the overall structure of what you're trying to do is wrong.
4. The whole implementation of `waitUntil()` is confused and I can't even tell what it's trying to actually wait for.
5. This is a server that can field lots of connections from lots of clients.  You can't just wait for the "next" socket.io connection and assume that connection is from the client you just got a request for.  The only way to associate a socket.io connection with an http request is to use some identifying characteristic in both (usually a cookie) and then in the http request, you get the cookie and look up the cookie to see if you currently have a socket.io connection that matches that cookie.  This is something that [express-socket.io-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-socket.io-session) helps with.

Unfortunately, you don't describe what you're really trying to accomplish here so I can't point you to a good solution.  All, I can really say here is that this scheme will not work.  If you want further help with the actual problem, please edit your question to include the problem description in words (not your coding issues).  Show the exact sequence of events you want to happen and explain what you're trying to accomplish and why.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Any idea how to check if client is connected with socket.io on server side? When I use express-session with combination of express-socket.io-session shouldn't socket.io cookie be the same as the user sessionID ? Shouldn't they use the same cookie?

Comment: @Proo1931 - socket.io has its own cookie that has nothing to do with the session so socket.io and express-session will each have separate cookies.  What express-socket-io-session allows you to do is to get access to the user's session object from within socket.io events.  So, when you receive the `connection` event for an incoming socket.io connection, you can get access to the session object for that user and access any state you have stored there or put state there.

Comment: @Proo1931 - If, when you get a `connection` event, you put the `socket` into the session object, then you can also get access to the socket.io socket from any express routes.  So, this allows you to send socket.io messages from express route handlers, but please note that is generally only useful if the route was hit by an Ajax call because if the route was hit by a browser page loading or a form POST, there is not yet a socket.io connection for the newly loaded page.

Comment: I decided to not use the express-socket.io-session module but to pass the express session middleware to socket. I have problem with detection when the user is connected via socket.io. "this allows you to send socket.io messages from express route handlers, but please note that is generally only useful if the route was hit by an Ajax call because if the route was hit by a browser page loading or a form POST, there is not yet a socket.io connection for the newly loaded page." thats is why I wait till socket connection is established and THEN I want to send for example some emits to specific room

Comment: But I dunno if req.session when moving by router.post is updated by socket.io connection (when it is established later on). It seems not - the router.post has old session data, without updated values from established socket connection, so then I wait for variable update that will never happen - your point number 2.