# Accessing the Data Object of Socket.IO-Server from the Socket.IO-Client

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

In socket.io server a property can be added to the `socket.data` object. How do I access such a property at the client side (`socket.io-client`)?.

**// Server code**

```
io.on('connection', socket => {
   socket.data.customId = getCustomId();
   io.emit('connected', {success: 'true'})
})
```

**// Client code**

```
socket = io('http://localhost:5000');

socket.on('connected', data => {
  console.log('SOCKET_DATA:', socket)
  console.log('SOCKET_CUSTOM-ID:', socket.data.customId); // produces 'undefined'
})
```

I would like to access the `customId` I added at the server from the client side. The `data` attribute don't even exist on the `socket` object displayed at the console at the client side.

Comment: The properties you add to the socket object exists only on the server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted some way to have access to that, you would have to create some request that sends to the server. Only the server stores that information. You could do something like the following on client side:

```
socket.emit("getCustomId", (id) => {
   console.log("SOCKET_CUSTOM-ID:", id);
});
```

Then the server can listen and respond with the custom id:

```
socket.on("getCustomId", (callback) => {
    callback(socket.data.customId);
});
```

That `callback` parameter on the server side connects back to the unnamed ES-6 function declared in the `socket.emit("getCustomId");` call, which you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20337832/is-socket-io-emit-callback-appropriate) on this SO question about `socket.io` callbacks